Is there away to compute Index values (base 100) from Year-over-Year % change (YoY) of the variable?
Let's assume I have a time series like this :



Time period
YoY Change (%)




Y2024 _ Q1
7.00


Y2024 _ Q2
4.85


Y2024 _ Q3
5.77


Y2024 _ Q4
5.66


Y2025 _ Q1
6.54


Y2025 _ Q2
6.48


Y2025 _ Q3
6.36


Y2025 _ Q4
6.25



Is there a way to convert the "YoY % Change" series into a "Index Value" series (with base 100 at a given date) ?
The target series would be something like :



Time period
Index (base 100 is at Y2023_Q1)




Y2023 _ Q1
100


Y2023 _ Q2
103


Y2023 _ Q3
104


Y2023 _ Q4
106


Y2024 _ Q1
107


Y2024 _ Q2
108


Y2024 _ Q3
110


Y2024 _ Q4
112


Y2025 _ Q1
114


Y2025 _ Q2
115


Y2025 _ Q3
117


Y2025 _ Q4
119



Or maybe it is not possible to re-construct the data from 2023 Q1, so maybe I should aim instead to build something like this, with fixing the base reference (index = 100) in 2024Q1  :



Time period
Index (base 100 = Y2024_Q1)




Y2024 _ Q1
100


Y2024 _ Q2
1XX


Y2024 _ Q3
1XX


Y2024 _ Q4
etc.



If we have quartetly data, I know we can compute Year-over-Year % Change from Index with :
$$\frac{\mathbf{Index}_{Year\_Y, Quarter\_Q}-\mathbf{Index}_{Year\_(Y-1), Quarter\_Q}}{ \mathbf{Index}_{Year \_(Y-1), Quarter\_Q}}$$
But the only data I have is YoY, and I would like to reverse back to Index values. Is there a practical way to do that ?

I cannot discern the relationship you are trying to illustrate.  Could you please explain what you mean by an "index value"?

It is explained here : https://www.dallasfed.org/research/basics/indexing
Index value would be a way to represent any variable (for instance, population of a country) with respect to a reference date. The reference date gets the value 100 (this 100 has no unit, it's not expressed in citizens or people, it just represents 100%). Every other value is expressed as a percentage of the 100. If we have
Population of US - year 1 = 330 M
Population of US - year 2 = 346,5 M
We can re-arrange the data as :
Population of US - year 1 = 100
Population of US - year 2 = 105

(Because if 330 M increases by 5%, it gives 346,5 M. Therefore it makes sense to state that an American population of 330M today and 346,5M tomorrow is akin as American population going from index 100 to index 105). I hope it's clear (it seems that this way of expressing a statistical variable is somewhat popular with official European Union statistics but not so much in other uses).

Sure, that's standard.  The problem is that your example data don't appear to do anything like this.

If all you have are YoY data, by quarter, then no, you can not recover the index for all quarters.
Say you assign $100$ (arbitrary units, or au) to 2023Q1; you can deduce that 2024Q1 is now $107$ (based on your YoY 7% change). Now, for 2024Q2, it is 4.85% more than 2023Q2; but you do not know how 2023Q2 compares to $100$, aka 2023Q1. You are stuck... (same for Q3 and Q4).
If you had quarter-over-quarter (QoQ) change data, by quarter you could recreate the quarterly indeces; if you had YoY change data, by year, you could recreate the yearly indeces. But all you can do here is get indeces for Q1, and Q1 alone (as you did; 100, 107, 114).

I had not thought about the "QoQ" solution at quartertly time step, this would indeed do the trick I attended to do which is trying to see what I can get in my models with a series of levels instead of variations. Now I just have to check if I have indeed QoQ data available, or if not, YoY at yearly intervals as you suggest. Thanks for the help !
